# Classes that represent processes

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns

Please see the code below:

```
    Public Class SystemCheck
    public Overridable sub Check(ByVal RecordID As Integer, ByVal SystemID As Integer) As Boolean
        'Generic code to check a system
    And Sub
End Class

Public Cass MarketingSystemCheck
    Inherits SystemCheck
    public Overrides function Check(ByVal RecordID As Integer, ByVal SystemID As Integer) As Boolean
        'Code to check Marketing system specifically
    And function
End Class

Public Cass Sales SalesSystemCheck
    Inherits SystemCheck

    public Overrides function Check(ByVal RecordID As Integer, ByVal SystemID As Integer) As Boolean
        'Code to check Marketing system specifically
    And function

End Class
```

The classes check if a record is ready for deletion.  SystemCheck.Check can be used to check a RecordID from many systems e.g. Production, Finance etc.

My question is: is it bad practice to have classes that represent a process e.g. SystemCheck instead of a thing e.g. Person.  Someone said to me today that classes should represent things rather than processes but I still am not sure.

Comment: Processes are things, at least conceptually.  There's no rule that says a class must only represent a physical three-dimensional real-world thing.  Classes should represent individual "things" which may have physical analogues or may not, but more importantly classes should represent conceptual separations of concerns.  If a "process" can be encapsulated with its own descriptors, its own functionality, and its own single reason to change then I see no reason why it shouldn't be a class.  Perhaps the person who suggested this can elaborate on an alternative to your design?

Comment: @David, thanks that is what I thought.  Could you post an answer?

Comment: Classes can be anything and should not always represent *real world objects/things*, otherwise it would have been impossible to create abstractions (and thus restricting a huge area of possibilities that can be accomplished with programming).

Answer (score 3):

Processes are things, at least conceptually.

There's no rule that says a class must only represent a physical three-dimensional real-world thing. Classes should represent individual "things" which may have physical analogues or may not, but more importantly classes should represent conceptual separations of concerns.

If a "process" can be encapsulated with its own descriptors, its own functionality, and its own single reason to change then I see no reason why it shouldn't be a class. (Perhaps the person who suggested this can elaborate on an alternative to your design?)

More important than what your classes represent are the principles which drive good object-oriented design.  A great set of such principles are [the S.O.L.I.D. principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

If a "process" is *related to* some object which represents a "thing" then it's *possible* that the process could be refactored to be a part of that "thing."  But there may be very compelling reasons why it shouldn't.  If the "process" and the "thing" need to be modified independently of one another then consolidating them would introduce a dependency such that when one changes both need to be re-tested.

Sometimes separating concepts into their own classes may not even have anything to do with any particular object oriented principle and is simply a matter of refactoring for readability and maintainability.  I think a classic example of this is the [Replace Method With Method Object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Emyyp8giuf0) refactoring pattern.

Don't be afraid of making more classes.  They encapsulate logic and data very effectively.  "Too many classes" only becomes a problem when business concepts become stretched *so* thinly that they're laid out across multiple classes.  For example, if adding a field to a form in a UI involves modifying tons of classes all the way up the development stack, then perhaps there are too many.  (Or at least too many which have the same structure or do roughly the same thing.)